# Is there a good thesaurus for slangs?

Tags: resources, thesaurus

If you use rhymezone, you can only get 2 synonym for the word penis, but if you look at the slangs for penis, there's 100 different slangs for it, so I am wondering what might be the best slang thesaurus on the Internet. I need it so I can write dialogues for people who belong to some street gangs in my next novel.

Comment: urbanthesaurus.org

Comment: urbanthesaurus.org looks really good. Maybe post an answer so I can share and accept it as an answer.

Comment: I just found out that Urban Thesaurus exists. This is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly,you can find a few of them. Here's a good example or british slang and I'll add in the swear words: https://www.oxfordinternationalenglish.com/dictionary-of-british-slang/
https://www.indy100.com/viral/british-swear-word-ranked-offensiveness-2657274989
Just look around.